# How to protect breaking app when state is initialized by props of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to protect state from breaking when props `native_langugaes[0]` does not exist?

This is how I tried to protect, but app break when `native_langugages[0]` does not exist:

```
 this.state = {
      language: props.currentDocument.native_languages[0] || 'en',
 };
```

Comment: that should work. the only case I can think of the above might break is if `native_languages` itself doesn't exist in the props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `native_languages` does not exist either. Try to use `lodash.get`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get

```js
this.state = {
   language: get(props, 'currentDocument.native_languages[0]', 'en'),
};
```

Comment: Does `lodash.get` will resolve and put `defaultValue` if props is not 'undefined', I mean if is like an empty array?

Comment: It has to be false to return default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a ternary:

```
this.state = {
  language: props.currentDocument.native_languages 
    ? props.currentDocument.native_languages[0] || 'en' 
    : 'en'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

While all suggestions seems good, you should consider taking a look at [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) as it seems to me a cleaner way to do it.